# Can I use geth light sync for mining purpose

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ether

Iam new to this, 
I wanna start mining ethereum, I have tried over 5 times to fast sync geth, with ethereum wallet and failed to do so, as it would get stuck, sometimes my pc froze, would take days even though geth fast sync wasn't interrupted, so I had enough of it..

Now I wanna know if I can start mining with a light sync of geth, would that be plausible and what would I lose with light sync over the normal fast sync?

Please help, sorry for being a noob 
Thank you in advance :) 
*WELP*

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?